# Disable Http Delete in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to disable HTTP delete in Spring MVC. I tried Interceptor but it doesnt work for Delete requests.
In my AppInitializer

```
@Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setInitParameter("dispatchDeleteRequest", "true");
    }
```

tried this.

I am making a call of the form

```
OPTIONS /<Website>/ HTTP/1.0
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0)
Host: XYZ.com
```

And the response I am getting is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Date: Mon, 10 Nov 2014 10:51:02 GMT
Connection: close
```

UPDATE :-One way I can think of doing it

```
@Controller
public class HandleDeleteRequest{

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public boolean handleDeleteRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        logger.info(request.getMethod());
        if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE")) {
            // Not a POST/GET - send error and return false
            logger.error("Not Get or Put request");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Unauthorized Request");
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

}
```

But this one doesnt seem to be appropriate

Comment: do you want this across the application or for a specific url.

Comment: I need it across the app